# Ubuntu 14.04LTS TCP Connection drop

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, minecraft

I am having dedi machine with ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on it. And recently I've noticed that my players (as I host minecraft server) get kicked from the server with message saying connection was closed by the remote host. Furthermore, it seems like those who are "afk" meaning almost none data transfer are the ones who get kicked, so I am kindly asking, what could becausing TCP connections to drop if they are almost idle?

I have currently clean iptables due to this problem. Also I am usign 5 IPs on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

If NAT is being used anywhere (including your client's router), then conntrack may drop idle connections.

You may try setting up TCP keepalive to prevent this, by enforcing minimum activity on all connections even when they are idle. Check /proc/sys/net/ipv(4|6)/tcp_keepalive_*

Comment: I've opened /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_* and currently theres these default values

tcp_keepalive_time = 7200 (seconds)
tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75 (seconds)
tcp_keepalive_probes = 9 (number of probes)